# Can't Connect to MongoDB in Cloud9 with express-generator template

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cloud9-ide

I'm using the express-generator in Cloud9 and haven't been able to connect my node application to mongodb.  I can get mongodb running just fine, but as soon as I try to do 'npm start' to run my node app and get it connected, I just get an error.  The part of the error that seems most important is that the application fails when it tries to run /bin/www which seems to be the express-generator's version of what most people seem to name their 'server.js' file.  Any help would be deeply appreciated. Here is my error output:

```
dc3314@nihongo-mnemonics:~/workspace/nihongo-mnemonics (master) $ npm start 
> nihongo-mnemonics@0.0.0 start /home/ubuntu/workspace/nihongo-mnemonics
> node ./bin/www
/home/ubuntu/workspace/nihongo-mnemonics/node_modules/mongoose
/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:228
process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:896:19)
npm ERR! nihongo-mnemonics@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nihongo-mnemonics@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the nihongo-mnemonics
package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls nihongo-mnemonics
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.14.13-c9
npm ERR! command "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu
/.nvm/v0.10.35/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/workspace/nihongo-mnemonics
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/workspace/nihongo-mnemonics/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var app = express();


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//connect to local database 
mongoose.connect("mongodb://"+process.env.IP+":27017/data/mydb");
// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error', {
message: err.message,
error: err
});
});
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error', {
message: err.message,
error: {}
});
});


module.exports = app;
```

And /bin/www:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
* Module dependencies.
*/

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('nihongo-mnemonics:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
* Get port from environment and store in Express.
*/

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
* Create HTTP server.
*/

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
* Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
*/

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
* Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
*/

function normalizePort(val) {
var port = parseInt(val, 10);

if (isNaN(port)) {
// named pipe
return val;
}

if (port >= 0) {
// port number
return port;
}

return false;
}

/**
* Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
*/

function onError(error) {
if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
throw error;
}

var bind = typeof port === 'string'
? 'Pipe ' + port
: 'Port ' + port;

// handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
switch (error.code) {
case 'EACCES':
console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
process.exit(1);
break;
case 'EADDRINUSE':
console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
process.exit(1);
break;
default:
throw error;
}
}

/**
* Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
*/

function onListening() {
var addr = server.address();
var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
? 'pipe ' + addr
: 'port ' + addr.port;
debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would replace this line

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://"+process.env.IP+":27017/data/mydb");
```

with

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb");
```

I know they recommend that you use process.env.IP instead but I didn't have any luck doing that. Also Mongoose expects the database name after the "...27017/...". You have the file path instead. Even though your db might be in folder data mongoose only wants the db name. Even if the actual db doesn't have any records it will create the db and name it with what follows the "27017/...".

Good luck! Hope this helps